# Can't load new url using if / else javascript statement - help?

Tags: javascript

I've appropriated some code to create a countdown timer for the launch of a new site. The timer itself, which uses a custom typeface, works very well.

However, when the if / else statement for `timesup` is true and goes to 'else', I can't get any other function to work apart from the way you see it below:

```
function formatresults(){
    if (this.timesup==false){//if target date/time not yet met
        var displaystring="<div class='row'><div class='col'> "+arguments[0]+" </div> <div class='thincol'>&#149;</div> <div class='col'> "+arguments[1]+" </div> <div class='thincol'>&#149;</div><div class='col'>  "+arguments[2]+" </div> <div class='thincol'>&#149;</div> <div class='col'> "+arguments[3]+" </div> </div>"
    }
    else {
        var displaystring = "BAR"
    }
    return displaystring
}
```

if I change `var displaystring` to `window.location` (to load the full site at the end of the countdown), the timer ceases to work completely.

I know this is due to a fundamental misunderstanding of javascript in a way, but in all honesty I've developed sites using javascript and libraries like jquery and mootools and haven't hit a brick wall like this in a long time.

If you have any advice, please do share it with me!

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have a serious issue of no formatting madness going on. You should properly indent and format your JavaScript and terminate each statement with a semicolon:

```
function formatresults() {
   var displaystring = "";

   if (this.timesup == false) { // if target date/time not yet met
       displaystring = "<div class='row'><div class='col'> "
                     + arguments[0]
                     + " </div> <div class='thincol'>&#149;</div> <div class='col'> "
                     + arguments[1]
                     + " </div> <div class='thincol'>&#149;</div><div class='col'>  "
                     + arguments[2]
                     + " </div> <div class='thincol'>&#149;</div> <div class='col'> "
                     + arguments[3]
                     + " </div> </div>";
  } else {
    displaystring = "CRAP";
    window.location.href = "http://example.com/";
  }

  return displaystring
}
```

The above code should work just fine. Now I don't know why you would want to redirect the user after having set `displaystring`, since that will abort the current page execution, but nonetheless; the above code should work.

As Ben Lee writes; you shouldn't be doing `window.location.href` changes in this function, but instead in the function invoking `formatresults()` so `formatresults()` only does what it says, which is to format the results. This is how I'd solve it:

```
function formatresults() {
   var result = { success : false, value : null };

   if (this.timesup) { // if target date/time not yet met
       result.success = false;
       result.value = "Time's up!";
   } else {
       result.success = true;
       result.value = "<div class='row'><div class='col'> "
                    + arguments[0]
                    + " </div> <div class='thincol'>&#149;</div> <div class='col'> "
                    + arguments[1]
                    + " </div> <div class='thincol'>&#149;</div><div class='col'>  "
                    + arguments[2]
                    + " </div> <div class='thincol'>&#149;</div> <div class='col'> "
                    + arguments[3]
                    + " </div> </div>";
  }

  return result;
}

// ...

var result = formatresults();

if (!result.success) {
    window.location.href = "http://example.com/";
} else {
    // Do something with result.value
}
```

Comment: asbjonu... this was the answer to my problems. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out. I totally realise that the code was a bit of a mess, so first thing I did was tidy it up. Placing `location.href` under the `displaystring` variable completely solved my problem. If anyone wants to use the timer code I've laid out just email me!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just immediately redirect in the `else` clause?

```
function formatresults() {
    if (this.timesup == false) {
        return "<div class='row'><div class='col'> "+arguments[0]+" </div> <div class='thincol'>&#149;</div> <div class='col'> "+arguments[1]+" </div> <div class='thincol'>&#149;</div><div class='col'>  "+arguments[2]+" </div> <div class='thincol'>&#149;</div> <div class='col'> "+arguments[3]+" </div> </div>";
    } else {
        window.location.href = "http://url.to.full.site";
    }
}
```

*Really the check doesn't belong in `formatresults`, you should try to move it out into whatever function called `formatresults`. I just did it this way for demo purposes, since I don't have a sample of your calling code.*

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks so much for your reply. I'd had a problem introducing the `window.location.href` function without also including the original `var displaystring` part as shown below. Many thanks again, I appreciate you taking the time to help me!